# Printing array output in PHP in a readable format

Tags: php

I'm trying to print **multiple values** user has selected on form submit. However with following what I'm seeing is only the last element printed **irrespective whether it is selected or not.**

Note that the print on the screen I'm looking at is a print that a layman can understand!

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //I'm trying to show the user these are the values you've selected
    print_r($option['name']);
    }
    ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER[" PHP_SELF "]);?>">
        <td class="container">
            <select multiple name="mercha_A[]" class="selectpicker form-control" title="Merchandiser type">
      <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $option['value']; ?>" <?php echo (isset($_POST[ 'mercha_A']) && in_array($option[ 'value'], $_POST[ 'mercha_A'])) ? ' selected="selected"' : ''; ?>>
                <?php echo $option['name']; ?>
            </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
        </td>
        <td><button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button></td>
    </form>
```

Anyone needs a coffee on my account?

Answer (score 3):

wrap your `print_r` in `<pre>` Tags

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($option['name']);
echo "</pre>;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST['mercha_A']); // you have to print the name attribute not option
echo "</pre>;
```

Answer (score 1):

depending on your situation, you could use either of these, I think the last will best suite those who don't have a programming background. Because, I think JSON is a human readable format.

### Method 1:

```
echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST['mercha_A']); echo '</pre>';
```

### Method 2:

```
echo json_encode($_POST['mercha_A']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to print

```
$_POST['mercha_A'];
```

Otherwise, `$option['name']` is completely undefined in your case, but even if you put the `print_r()` at the end of the script, it would only be the name of the last option in `$options`.

In order to make `print_r()` readable, you can View Source (Ctrl+U) in your browser, or wrap it in `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: You're right! however even if I wrap the `print_r()` with a `<pre>` tags I'm seeing an output like this --> `Array
(
    [0] => Hello
    [1] => World
)` . How do I print that so one sees it as "Hello World"?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do. To concatenate strings in an array use `implode()`, but this is not always the most desirable way to print arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Using `extbase` debugger from TYPO3.

Check it out it's insane :) https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/master/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Utility/DebuggerUtility.php

It helps you to debug `arrays` and `object` in a readable way

```
DebuggerUtility::var_dump($array)
```